# snowflake Computation for dividing 2 columns giving wrong values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am exactly doing this Sum(2322933.99/1161800199.8)*
100
I should get
1.9 something but I am getting 64. Something
can anyone guide my y this division in snowflake giving wrong results
I tried them converting into decimal values and tried with Formula div0()
Nothing worked

Comment: Why aggregate function `SUM` over expression built only from constants? Please post the query are you using

Comment: Why are you using aggregate function `sum()`? You would probably need to show us your entire query.

Comment: It is like sum(total gross weight /total cases filled)*100 final set has 2700 records

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your database table has 33 rows. So you get 33 * 1.9 (because of SUM), which is about 64.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, with the few details that you gave us:

- `sum(x)/sum(y)` is different than `sum(x/y)`

```
1/2 + 2/4 + 4/8 = 1.5
(1+2+4)/(2+4+8) = 0.5
```

Try writing `sum(total gross weight)/sum(total cases filled)` instead of `sum(total gross weight /total cases filled)`.